# Miscellaneous series

Tags: sequences-and-series

[image]

Hi, I need help with this question. We have to add first n terms of the series, when n is even. I understand that we can assume that n = 2m, where m belongs to the set of natural numbers. But the way it has been solved, that's what I don't understand. It says S(n) = S(2m), which is obvious. What I don't understand is, that result : m[2m³+4m²+5m+2], that's S(m), i.e. sum of first m terms, right? Then we put m = 2m in order to find out the sum of first 2m terms. But the book says that the expression m[2m³+4m²+5m+2] is S(2m), i.e sum of first 2m terms. How? Isn't it the sum of first m terms?

Comment: Is the first term $1^3$ or is it $1^3+3\times 2^2$ ?

Comment: Does the result $m[2m^3+4m^2+5m+2]$ represent $S(m)$ or does it represent $S(2m)$ ?

Comment: That's what I was wondering too. But I think it's 1³ + 3 × 2²

Comment: I know that's exactly where you're making a mistake. The first term is just $1^3$.

Comment: Exactly what I am trying to understand, and that's my question. That result is supposed to be S(m), from what I understand. Book says it's S(2m). I don't understand why?

Comment: Easy, that result is S(n) and since n=2m, that result is also S(2m).

Comment: If you're like me, you're getting confused because they "seem" to be summing first "m" terms at the first line of the solution. But if you look carefully, they're actually summing the first 2m terms.

Comment: That's exactly what I don't understand. I think they are summing first 'm' terms. I get it, that S(n) = S(2m)

Comment: Is the first term really just 1³ ?

Comment: Yes, its just $1^3$ and the second term is just $3\times 2^2$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79262/discussion-between--times-e-and-rsadhvika).

Comment: In series, the terms are usually separated by $+$ if no explicit instructions are given and assuming your prof is not a psycho

Answer (score 1):

Look carefully, the sum given is $S_{2m}$, not $S_m$, so we substitute $n =2m$ in the end. Basically we are summing $2m$ terms, not $m$ terms. The expression given is for sum of $2m$ terms.